# Style HR with Image

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve something as close to the image below as possible.
[image]

I currently get the following with the code below and can't seem to quite get it to do what I need.

Current Styling:
[image]

My CSS:

```
hr:after { 
    background: url('../img/green_leaf.png') no-repeat top center;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 18px; /* height of the ornament */
    position: relative;
    top: -9px; /* half the height of the ornament */
    border: 0;
    color: #d7d7d7;
}
```

I Would like to thicken the line, and if possible, add space around the image (without making the green_leaf.png have a white bg).

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176262/how-to-make-space-between-middle-line-and-text/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about setting the image in the `hr` element, and using `:before` and `:after` to create the lines? That way you won't have to set a background on the image to cover up a single line.

## Working Example:

```css
hr { 
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Aip.png') no-repeat top center;
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    height: 18px;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
}
hr:before,
hr:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #d7d7d7;
    height: 2px;
    top: 8px;
}
hr:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
hr:after {
    right: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I wanted to avoid adding extra DIV's and keep the ability to simply use the HR tag, this works EXACTLY as needed!  Thanks a TON!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in this post [Custom <hr> with image/character in the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202089/custom-hr-with-image-character-in-the-center)

I modified it and I got this:

```
hr {
  no-repeat top center;
  text-align: center; /* horizontal centering */
  line-height: 1px; /* vertical centering */
  height: 1px; /* gap between the lines */
  border-width: 1px 0; /* top and bottom borders */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #676767;
}

hr:after {
  content: ""; /* section sign */
  background: url('smiley.gif') no-repeat top center;
  display: inline; /* for vertical centering and background knockout */
  background-color: white; /* same as background color */
  padding: 0 2em; /* size of background color knockout */
}
```

Pay attention to `padding: 0 2em;` and `background-color: white;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you set it up like this, and specify background color on the image to match whatever you have in the background of the page (probably white) it will look good:

HTML

```
<div class='hr'>
    <hr>
    <img src='../img/green_leaf.png' alt=''>
</div>
```

CSS

```
hr {
    border:none;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}

.hr { 
    text-align: center;
}

.hr img {
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
    background:white;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

Result:
[image]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ptdho8p/1/)